# strange entries in ufw log

Tags: networking, server, firewall, ufw, deluge

I have a very permissive firewall configuration, where I have almost all ports open:

```
$ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: allow (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Anywhere                   ALLOW IN    127.0.0.1
Anywhere                   ALLOW IN    10.0.0.0/16
53                         DENY IN     Anywhere
27017                      DENY IN     Anywhere
5335                       DENY IN     Anywhere
```

I don't understand then why I'm seeing these UFW BLOCK entries in my log:

```
Apr 16 21:28:04 hostname kernel: [20920.490239] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=xx:xx:xx SRC=MY_PUBLIC_IP DST=10.0.0.40 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=62 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=60369 DPT=58946 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
Apr 16 21:28:09 hostname kernel: [20925.495136] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=xx:xx:xx SRC=MY_PUBLIC_IP DST=10.0.0.40 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=62 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=45545 DPT=58946 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
Apr 16 21:28:11 hostname kernel: [20927.479072] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=xx:xx:xx SRC=MY_PUBLIC_IP DST=10.0.0.40 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=62 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=58433 DPT=58946 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
Apr 16 21:28:12 hostname kernel: [20928.481887] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=xx:xx:xx SRC=MY_PUBLIC_IP DST=10.0.0.40 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=62 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=44041 DPT=58946 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
Apr 16 21:28:12 hostname kernel: [20928.489277] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=xx:xx:xx SRC=MY_PUBLIC_IP DST=10.0.0.40 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=62 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=55645 DPT=58946 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
Apr 16 21:28:13 hostname kernel: [20929.493087] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=xx:xx:xx SRC=MY_PUBLIC_IP DST=10.0.0.40 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=62 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=50245 DPT=58946 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
Apr 16 21:28:13 hostname kernel: [20929.493358] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=xx:xx:xx SRC=MY_PUBLIC_IP DST=10.0.0.40 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=62 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=56409 DPT=58946 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
```

They all have my public IP as the source and my private IP as the destination. The destination port is always 58946 (deluged). Even if I explicitly allow this port (which shouldn't be needed), I still get these entries in the log.

Any idea why this is happening and what it means?

EDIT:

Adding full iptables rules:

```
$ sudo iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-N DOCKER-USER
-N monitorix_IN_0
-N monitorix_IN_1
-N monitorix_IN_2
-N monitorix_IN_3
-N monitorix_OUT_0
-N monitorix_OUT_1
-N monitorix_OUT_2
-N monitorix_OUT_3
-N ts-forward
-N ts-input
-N ufw-after-forward
-N ufw-after-input
-N ufw-after-logging-forward
-N ufw-after-logging-input
-N ufw-after-logging-output
-N ufw-after-output
-N ufw-before-forward
-N ufw-before-input
-N ufw-before-logging-forward
-N ufw-before-logging-input
-N ufw-before-logging-output
-N ufw-before-output
-N ufw-logging-allow
-N ufw-logging-deny
-N ufw-not-local
-N ufw-reject-forward
-N ufw-reject-input
-N ufw-reject-output
-N ufw-skip-to-policy-forward
-N ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-N ufw-skip-to-policy-output
-N ufw-track-forward
-N ufw-track-input
-N ufw-track-output
-N ufw-user-forward
-N ufw-user-input
-N ufw-user-limit
-N ufw-user-limit-accept
-N ufw-user-logging-forward
-N ufw-user-logging-input
-N ufw-user-logging-output
-N ufw-user-output
-A INPUT -j ts-input
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 32400 --dport 1024:65535 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j monitorix_OUT_3
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 32400 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j monitorix_IN_3
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 53 --dport 1024:65535 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j monitorix_OUT_2
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j monitorix_IN_2
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 --dport 1024:65535 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j monitorix_OUT_1
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j monitorix_IN_1
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 --dport 1024:65535 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j monitorix_OUT_0
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j monitorix_IN_0
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-reject-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-track-input
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-b1f439913694 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-b1f439913694 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i br-b1f439913694 ! -o br-b1f439913694 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br-b1f439913694 -o br-b1f439913694 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-8c2ef18e8cce -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-8c2ef18e8cce -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i br-8c2ef18e8cce ! -o br-8c2ef18e8cce -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br-8c2ef18e8cce -o br-8c2ef18e8cce -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-13f24cfcf7be -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-13f24cfcf7be -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i br-13f24cfcf7be ! -o br-13f24cfcf7be -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br-13f24cfcf7be -o br-13f24cfcf7be -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-cd92e6b2b4c4 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-cd92e6b2b4c4 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i br-cd92e6b2b4c4 ! -o br-cd92e6b2b4c4 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br-cd92e6b2b4c4 -o br-cd92e6b2b4c4 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j ts-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-reject-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-track-forward
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 32400 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j monitorix_OUT_3
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 32400 --dport 1024:65535 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j monitorix_IN_3
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j monitorix_OUT_2
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 53 --dport 1024:65535 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j monitorix_IN_2
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j monitorix_OUT_1
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 --dport 1024:65535 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j monitorix_IN_1
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j monitorix_OUT_0
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 --dport 1024:65535 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j monitorix_IN_0
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-reject-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-track-output
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.2/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.3/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 58946 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.3/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 58846 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.3/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8112 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.4/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8181 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.5/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.20.0.3/32 ! -i br-13f24cfcf7be -o br-13f24cfcf7be -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8081 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.20.0.4/32 ! -i br-13f24cfcf7be -o br-13f24cfcf7be -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7777 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-b1f439913694 ! -o br-b1f439913694 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-8c2ef18e8cce ! -o br-8c2ef18e8cce -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-13f24cfcf7be ! -o br-13f24cfcf7be -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-cd92e6b2b4c4 ! -o br-cd92e6b2b4c4 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-b1f439913694 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-8c2ef18e8cce -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-13f24cfcf7be -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-cd92e6b2b4c4 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
-A ts-forward -i tailscale0 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x40000/0xff0000
-A ts-forward -m mark --mark 0x40000/0xff0000 -j ACCEPT
-A ts-forward -s 100.64.0.0/10 -o tailscale0 -j DROP
-A ts-forward -o tailscale0 -j ACCEPT
-A ts-input -s 100.106.250.67/32 -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A ts-input -s 100.115.92.0/23 ! -i tailscale0 -j RETURN
-A ts-input -s 100.64.0.0/10 ! -i tailscale0 -j DROP
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 137 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 138 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 139 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 445 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-logging-forward -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-before-forward -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 12 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -j ufw-user-forward
-A ufw-before-input -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 12 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p udp -m udp --sport 67 --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-not-local
-A ufw-before-input -d 224.0.0.251/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -d 239.255.255.250/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 1900 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-user-input
-A ufw-before-output -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -j ufw-user-output
-A ufw-logging-allow -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "
-A ufw-logging-deny -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j RETURN
-A ufw-logging-deny -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type MULTICAST -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-not-local -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-forward -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-input -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-output -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-track-input -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-track-input -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-track-output -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-track-output -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m udp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -s 127.0.0.1/32 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -s 10.0.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j DROP
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j DROP
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 27017 -j DROP
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m udp --dport 27017 -j DROP
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5335 -j DROP
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m udp --dport 5335 -j DROP
-A ufw-user-limit -m limit --limit 3/min -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
-A ufw-user-limit -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A ufw-user-limit-accept -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: What flavor/version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ufw is just a front end for iptables. We would have to see the iptables rule set  to be able to authoritatively comment. Note that ufw generated iptables rule sets are difficult to read and follow. (I do not like them).

However, notice that your listed BLOCK log entries are for TCP packets with the Reset bit asserted. For TCP connections, Linux tends to use a "half-duplex" close sequence where either side of the session can initiate connection termination via a single 2 way FIN-ACK handshake (which puts the connection into the CLOSE_WAIT state), instead of a full 4 way FIN-ACK handshake. This can, and does, lead to confusion between the understanding of the exact state of the TCP session between the two ends. In your case the other end thinks it still needs to reset the connection but meanwhile your end has terminated and forgotten about the connection and it is no longer in the connection tracking table. It is possible there never was an ESTABLISHED connection in the first place. The packet is blocked by UFW because it is perceived as attempting to start a NEW TCP session with incorrect TCP flag settings. The packet would have had to have the SYN bit set and the ACK, FIN and RST flags unset. The other flags bits are don't care.

Comment: Thanks, I added full iptables rules. There is indeed something about port 58946 there, apparently from docker.

Comment: If I understand your answer correctly, these should be innocuous and can be ignored?

Comment: Yes, those type of entries can be ignored. The important take away from this is to check the TCP flags.